Unknown smd component marked MN1Y4
I have an eMachines 443 motherboard with a problem — power is not going to the battery. I am trying to trace the circuit but have encountered some unknown components.
This is one of them — marked “MN1Y4”, a 6 pin dual (probably) something.
What is it and is there a site that has it in its list of markings?


What makes you think it's a dual something?

being in a power supply circuit it had to be a mosfet a transistor or possibly an op-amp...6 pins probably means  2 of one of them....

An op amp has at least five pins, so this definitely can't be a dual op amp. It looks like it is a dual MOSFET, but my first guess would have been a small switching controller.

This is DMN66D0LDW from Diodes Inc. It is a dual N-Channel MOSFET in a SOT363 package.

The Y4 is a date code, indicating April (4) 2011 (Y).
